# Simple environment check script

Tags: magento2, dependency

Is there a simple standalone PHP script that I can just put on a server and see if it meets the system requirements for Magento 2 to run?
For Magento 1 there is one going around by the name of [`magento-check.php`](https://gist.github.com/atomicpages/4383809) and it was pretty useful.
Is there something similar for Magento 2?